# Sub-domain setup doesn't work Apache 2.2.26 on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I tried setting up a sub-domain for my site example.com. It doesn't seem to resolve to the proper directory.

Below is my setup
Main domain: example.com
Subdomain: subdomain.example.com

DNS records: I have an A record for subdomain.example.com in Amazon Route 53 pointing to the IP address of the main domain.

In my httpd.conf located in /etc/httpd/conf/ I made the following changes

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
<Directory /var/www/subdomain>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I visit subdomain.example.com the browser returns me the index.html file from /var/www/html. Is there something that I am missing here, ideally it needs to return the index.html file from /var/www/subdomain.

Thank you!

### Update 1

I just checked subdomain.example.com/index.html - this returns the correct page. What do I need to do to make subdomain.example.com resolve the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a DirectoryIndex for your subdomain

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

The default DirectoryIndex is probably set to something else, and on an Amazon Linux AMI, when Apache can't find an index file, the 404 error handlers directs you to the index.html file in /var/www/html.

You'll be able to see that in the welcome.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

Comment: Thank you Garreth, that worked for me! I setup the directory index in the .htaccess file and it worked perfectly.

I'm still trying to figure out why Apache didn't read the index.html in the folder. Thank you for the info on the default error redirects - didn't know that earlier :)